# Not able to changes cards in Java Swing CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I have an class named AddAccounts

```
class AddAccounts extends JPanel {

    JPanel panelCont; //Panel deck
    CardLayout cl;

    public AddAccounts() {

             panelCont=new JPanel();
             cl = new CardLayout();
             panelCont.setLayout(cl);//set Panel Layout to CardLayout
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1013, 513));//Set Default Size

    /* Add Panels to the main window or integrate the panels*/
            panelCont.add(new Panel1(), "1");
            panelCont.add(new Panel2(),"2");
            panelCont.add(new Panel3(),"3");
            cl.show(panelCont, "1");
            add(panelCont);    
        }

    public void goNext() {
       cl.show(panelCont, "2");
      // cl.nxet(panelCont);
        System.out.println("method called"); //for debugging purpose
         }

    public void showFirstPanel(){
        cl.show(panelCont, "1");
         }  
}
```

And  two external(separate files) class named **Panel1 and panel2()**. and I wanna change the cards(**from panel1 to panel2**) when the button is being pressed in **panel1** that's why i create above listed method called goNext(),
but the problem is I'm not able to change the cards. here how i try to call the goNext()method **in Panel1**

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == nextBtn) {
        setMainCategory((String)mainCat.getSelectedItem());
    }
}
public void setMainCategory(String mainCategory){
    this.mainCategory=mainCategory;
   new AddAccounts().goNext();
    //System.out.println("From set Method: "+this.mainCategory);
}
```

Everything works fine, the **System.out.println("method called"); //for debugging purpose** get executed and printed on console window but the panels(card)are not changed.
please help.. how to make it work.

@haraldK 
what you said is absolutely correct. but it doesn't help me, concept i trying to implement is I have an JFrame named mainPanel and in mainPanel i have a JSplitPanel
`JSplitPane rootPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, userPanel, mainContentPane);`
mainContentPane consists

`JTabbedPane mainContentPane = new JTabbedPane();
        mainContentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 550));
        mainContentPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        mainContentPane.addTab("Your Database", new UserRecords());
        mainContentPane.addTab("Add Accounts", new AddAccounts());//here is the AddAccounts JPanel
        mainContentPane.addTab("Update Existing Data", new EditRecords());
        mainContentPane.setSelectedIndex(1);`

i place buttons on Panel1,Panel2 rather than placing buttons on parent Frame AddAccounts. Here the method goNext is belong to AddAccounts and i want to access it to change the panel(from 1 to 2) when the button is pressed in Panel1. i cannot call the goNext() method directly,since it is the method of AddAccounts class not Panel1. and `new AddAccounts().goNext();` doesn't help
Directory Structure:
     mypackage
      -UserPanel(MainPanelFrame,userPanelJPanel, mainContentPaneTabbedPane)
      -AddAccounts (goNext())
      -Panel1 (nextBtn)
      -Panel2 (nextBtn)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is *not* the `CardLayout` code, rather it is in the `setMainCategory` method:

```
new AddAccounts().goNext();
```

Here you create a new instance of the `AddAccounts` every time the method is invoked. The panel is flipped on this instance (that is why you see the debug output), but the component is never added to a parent (like a `JFrame` or `JPanel`) and thus never shown. After the method exits, the resulting component is just thrown away.

Instead, you need to add one single `AddAccounts` to a parent component, and in the `setMainCategory` method, you just invoke `goNext()` on this instance.

Here's a fully functional program that demonstrates everything I tried to explain above:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class CardLayoutTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayoutTest");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.getContentPane().add(new AddAccounts()); // Create single instance here
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    static class AddAccounts extends JPanel {

        JPanel panelCont; //Panel deck
        CardLayout cl;

        public AddAccounts() {
            panelCont = new JPanel();
            cl = new CardLayout();
            panelCont.setLayout(cl);//set Panel Layout to CardLayout

            /* Add Panels to the main window or integrate the panels*/
            panelCont.add(new ColorPanel(Color.ORANGE), "1");
            panelCont.add(new ColorPanel(Color.GRAY), "2");
            panelCont.add(new ColorPanel(Color.DARK_GRAY), "3");

            cl.show(panelCont, "1");

            add(panelCont);

            add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("First") {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    showFirstPanel();
                }
            }));
            add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Next") {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // This method is similar to your setMainCategory
                    goNext();
                }
            }));
        }

        public void goNext() {
//            cl.show(panelCont, "2");
            cl.next(panelCont); // Allows iterating through all panels
            System.out.println("method called"); //for debugging purpose
        }

        public void showFirstPanel() {
            cl.show(panelCont, "1");
        }

        /// Dummy class to show that page flipping works
        private class ColorPanel extends JPanel {
            public ColorPanel(Color background) {
                setOpaque(true);
                setBackground(background);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 200);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to create a functional example. Hope this will help you.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MyFrame
     */
    public MyFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        deck = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        firstCard = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        secondCard = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        deck.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

        firstCard.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("First");
        firstCard.add(jLabel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        deck.add(firstCard, "card2");

        secondCard.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("Second");
        secondCard.add(jLabel2, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        deck.add(secondCard, "card3");

        getContentPane().add(deck, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jButton1.setLabel("Go Next");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        ((CardLayout)deck.getLayout()).next(deck);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel deck;
    private javax.swing.JPanel firstCard;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel secondCard;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```